# Bot Builder SDK 4 How to work with attachments?

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

Bot Builder SDK 4 (dotnet) How to work with attachments ? I tried to use the example of BotBuilder-Samples 15.handling-attachments, but got 401 Unauthorized error with Skype channel.

```
foreach (var file in activity.Attachments)
{
    // Determine where the file is hosted.
    var remoteFileUrl = file.ContentUrl;

    // Save the attachment to the system temp directory.
    var localFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), file.Name)

    // Download the actual attachment
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        webClient.DownloadFile(remoteFileUrl, localFileName); <-- 401 here
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do ? Upload the attachment or download it?

Comment: Bot user uploads attachment (some text file) and I need to read and process it

Comment: Looks like you are not authorized to save a file to that directory, maybe try another directory or try saving the file to something like azure storage.

Comment: The problem is only with Skype channel, with webchat there is no error,  so problem not in local path

Comment: see what happens when you use an image (png, jpeg, etc) instead of a text file.  Skype is picky about what type of files it will let you use.

Comment: With png files I have the same problem

Comment: How are you attaching the file? Are you using the "Add files" button? or are you dragging-dropping the file? What version of Skype are you using? Also, what platform (Windows Universal (store app), etc)?

Comment: I use latest version of Skype desktop app ( 8.34.0.78) and "Add files" button.

Comment: I confirm the same error with Skype desktop app (8.41.0.54) and "Add files" button - while the same bot accepts exactly the same *.jpg and/ro *.png attachments in the Facebook messenger, Slack and Webchat channels attached to bot by botframework

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered solution at github.com discussion [Skype Can not receive attachment? #3623](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3623#issuecomment-337820207) which I also have just tested with success.

I see minimal modification to your code sample as follows:

```
string channelToken = null;

if ((activity.ChannelId.Equals("skype", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) 
{
    var credentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(youBotAppId, yourBotAppPassword);

    channelToken = await credentials.GetTokenAsync();
}

foreach (var file in activity.Attachments)
{
    // Determine where the file is hosted.
    var remoteFileUrl = file.ContentUrl;

    // Save the attachment to the system temp directory.
    var localFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), file.Name)

    // Download the actual attachment
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(channelToken))
        {
            webClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", channelToken);
        }

        webClient.DownloadFile(remoteFileUrl, localFileName);
    }
```